# parameters explanation of $_FILES in php

Tags: php

I am new to this site and i am sorry if anything wrong in my way of asking question.

I want to know about the parameters of `$_FILES` in php.

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
   //some code
}
```

By the above code, what is

`['uploadedfile']['name'] in $_FILES`

also in `move_uploaded_file($FILES['uploadedfile']['tmpname'])`

what is `tmpname`?

Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when the file is uploaded it is stored in the systems temp directory usually and assigned a name by the os - this name is the `tmpname`

Comment: So, is it not in hand of user?

Comment: Ok, understood @RamRaider

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['name']` is the Actual file name (as named on your computer).
`$_FILES['tmp_name']` is the temporary files name.

You computer automatically creates a temporary copy of the file that you are uploading in a temporary directory. 
This is the actual physical file uploaded by your computer.

Answer (score 1):

try this to learn about the content of $_FILES:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```